# Rails autoload having non-deterministic behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

I have two classes `app/responders/application_responder` and `app/responders/stripe/basic_responder`

I have code in `ApplicationResponder` like so:

```
class ApplicationResponder
    def self.responds_to(event_type, event_name)
        @@registered ||= []
        payload = {
            event_type: event_type,
            event_name: event_name,
            cls: self
        }
        @@registered << payload
    end

    def self.registered
        @@registered
    end
end
```

Then my basic responder registeres itself:

```
class Stripe::BasicResponder < ApplicationResponder

    responds_to :stripe, 'account.created'

    def respond(event)
        puts "foo!"
        pp event
    end

end
```

If I load up rails console and call `ApplicationResponder.registered` I'd expect to see a list of one element. Sometimes I do, sometimes it returns an empty list which to me suggests that stripe/basic_responder has not been evaluated yet?

Any ideas how to fix this?

I've tried adding responders to the eager load path in application.rb:

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/responders)
```

Comment: `config.eager_load_paths` only loads the files if caching is enabled. You would have to explicitly require the files for this to work in dev

Comment: "config.eager_load_paths accepts an array of paths from which Rails will eager load on boot if cache classes is enabled. Defaults to every folder in the app directory of the application."

Comment: You might also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819068/why-is-using-a-class-variable-in-ruby-considered-a-code-smell/40819118