# Ruby // Nokogiri trying to store selectors for various objects in a hash

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to store the selectors in hashes assigned to the appropriate topics which I will then scrape from a webpage.  However, when I do so, I am met with an 'undefined method' error for the "css" method.

Example:

```
@@letters_hash = {
      "a" => {
         uppercase: "A",
         history: css('div.class_1').css('div.class_2').text,
         url: "www.alphabet.com"
      }
}
```

Is there a way to encapsulate this?  Or, if I store it as a string, is there a way to remove the string and get it back to the methods?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean `css.('div.class_1')` or `css('div.class_1')`? I'm guessing that you're seeing an "undefined method call" exception.

Comment: sorry, the "css." was a typo.

Comment: Which call to `css` is giving you the undefined method error?

Comment: it is just giving me the line number, so I would assume it is the first one.
edit* when I remove the second one, I get the same error, so it is the first one.

Comment: So where is the `css` method supposed to come from?

Comment: it is a method that is part of the Nokogiri gem.  I want to be able to interpolate the 'value' from the hash in a scraper method later.
*edit: later it will look something like this `parsed_page.css('div.class_1').css('dic.class_2').text`

Comment: @MarcAuciello Are you getting ```NoMethodError (undefined method `css' for nil:NilClass)```?

Comment: BTW [Class variables probably don't do what you think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762366/are-ruby-class-variables-bad), use class instance variables instead.

Comment: @Schwern this is the exact error I am getting `undefined method `css' for Database:Class (NoMethodError)`  Also, it's part of a larger class, and it seems to only work if the hash is a class variable.  It seems to not play nice if I try to initialize it.  But, perhaps I am just doing that incorrectly as well.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`css('div.class_1').css('div.class_2').text` is `self.css('div.class_1').css('div.class_2').text` and `self` is your `Database` class. It doesn't have a css method. You need to call the method on something which has a css method like a Nokogiri node.

## Callbacks

If you want to store a set of methods to call on some Nokogiri node you'll get later, you make [a callback using a little anonymous function called a lambda](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/).

```
@letters = {
      "a" => {
         uppercase: "A",
         history: ->(node) { node.css('div.class_1').css('div.class_2').text },
         url: "www.alphabet.com"
      }
}
```

That takes a node as an argument and calls the methods on the node.

Then later when you have a node you can call this function.

```
@letters_hash[letter][:history].call(node)
```

## Objects

At this point it's getting compliated and should be encapsulated in an object.

```
class LetterTopic
  def initialize(letter)
    @letter = letter
  end

  def node_history(node)
    node.css('div.class_1').css('div.class_2').text
  end

  def uppercase
    @letter.upcase
  end

  def url
    "www.alphabet.com"
  end
end

letters = {
  "a" => LetterTopic.new("a")
}

node = ...get a Nokogiri node...

letters[letter].node_history(node)
```

## A Note About Class Variables

`@@letters_hash` ***does not do what you think***. Class variables in Ruby are shared by subclasses. If you subclass Database they will all share a single `@@letters_hash` variable.

```
class Database
  @@letters = {}

  def self.letters
    @@letters
  end
end

class Databasement < Database
end

Database.letters[:a] = 'database'
Databasement.letters[:a] = 'databasement'

p Database.letters     # {:a=>"databasement"}
p Databasement.letters # {:a=>"databasement"}
```

Instead, use Class Instance Variables. Like everything else in Ruby, the Database class is an object and can have its own instance variables.

```
class Database
  # Everything inside `class << self` works on the class object.
  class << self
    def letters
      @letters ||= {}
    end
  end
end

class Databasement < Database
end

Database.letters[:a] = 'database'
Databasement.letters[:a] = 'databasement'

p Database.letters       # {:a=>"database"}
p Databasement.letters   # {:a=>"databasement"}
```